# Momenta basis for a quantum system with configuration space $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, momentum, spherical-harmonics

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the configuration space of a (quantum) system.

- When $\mathcal{X} = S^1 \simeq \mathrm{SO}(2)$, a momenta basis is $$\{ |\ell\rangle : \ell \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$
- When $\mathcal{X} = \mathrm{SO}(3)$, a momenta basis is $$\{ |\ell,m,n\rangle : \ell,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ell \geq 0, -\ell \leq m,n \leq \ell \}.$$
- When $\mathcal{X} = S^2 \simeq \mathrm{SO}(3)/\mathrm{SO}(2)$, a momenta basis  is $$\{ | \ell,m\rangle: \ell,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \ell \geq 0, -\ell \leq m \leq \ell \}. $$

What is a momenta basis when $$\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \simeq \mathrm{SO}(3)/\mathrm{O}(2)~?$$

Comment: $RP^2$ is $S^2$ with antipodal points identified. So I would think you can just take the basis for $S^2$, and form states that are invariant under inversion e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|l, m\rangle+|l,-m\rangle)$.

Comment: Hi Eric Kubischta. Welcome to Phys.SE. I removed your last subquestion, which seemed _too broad._

Comment: @MengCheng Are you talking about the time reversal operator? Doesn't the parity operator act like $\pi | \ell,m\rangle = (-1)^\ell |\ell,m \rangle$? In which case we would throw away all of the odd $\ell$'s and  the momentum basis would be $\{ |\ell,m\rangle : \ell \in 2 \mathbb{Z}, m \in \mathbb{Z}, \ell  \geq 0, -\ell \leq m \leq \ell\}$.

Comment: @EricKubischta You are right, I confused inversion with time-reversal. Then indeed only the even $l$ are kept.